# How can I change direction of scrolling from right to left in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, horizontal-scrolling

I build a calculator. I put some symbols on the right side of the screen. When size of the screen is not enough, symbols on the left side disappear and HorizontalScrollView add some space to the right side.

[image]

[image]

How can I change directon of scrolling form left to right?

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/top_scr_v"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_view_margin">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/top_scr_hor_sc_v"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/resultValue"
                android:textColor="@color/mainColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/display_text_size"
                />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After API 17 you can use                 `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` , before  `android:supportsRtl="true"`.